# Angular JS how to get templateUrl in Directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am a starter in AngularJS. Now I am facing a problem. I build a web in `spingMVC and AngularJS`. I want to use directive to display my header part. When I write the directive templateUrl, I always get **Not Found(404)**. Is there anybody can tell me how to get the correct path here. There is my web application structure.

[image]

My dispathcer-servlet file is:

```
<mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/WEB-INF/resources/"/>
<mvc:resources mapping="/view/**" location="/WEB-INF/view/"/>
<mvc:resources mapping="/customJS/**" location="/WEB-INF/customJS/"/>
```

In main.js I write:

```
app.directive('naviDirective', function(){
    return {
        retstrict: 'EA',
        templateUrl: '/view/header.jsp',
        controller: function(){
             console.log("hea[enter image description here][1]der");
         }
    };

});
```

In home.jsp I write:

```
<navi-directive></navi-directive>
```

When I load home.js page, the console can print "header", but I get 
`"angular.min.js:103 GET http://localhost:8080/view/header.jsp 404 (Not Found)".`

Who can tell me how to fix this path. Thank you very much

Comment: Does your `view` directory sits in the root directory?

Comment: No, it is under WEB-INF folder. WEB-INF is under webContent

Comment: This problem has nothing to do with angular itself. Try opening that same url in your browser directly  and will have same problem. We don't know how your server routing is configured

Comment: main.js is under CustomJS. CustomJS is under WEB-INF folder.

Comment: So your templateUrl is incorrect... have you tried removing the slash at the beginning of your url and give the full path?

Comment: Yes I have tried to remove the slash at beginning, but it is incorrect.

Comment: <mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/WEB-INF/resources/"/><mvc:resources mapping="/view/**" location="/WEB-INF/view/"/>
<mvc:resources mapping="/customJS/**" location="/WEB-INF/customJS/"/>
This is my dispatcher-servlet.

Comment: You need to tag this question appropriately.

Comment: what is the name of the project and the url of the page in the project

Comment: MusicBox is my project name.

Comment: http://localhost:8080/MusicBox/ is my url